# Recursive File Search Is Missing Sub-Dirs

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a folder structure similar to this

> D:\Main\
>   
> D:\Main\Folder1\

My code below will scan any files in the `D:\Main\` dir, but it misses the `D:\Main\Folder1\` sub-dir.  I thought that setting the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` would have all sub-dirs be scanned, but it is not the case for me, as when my `foreach` loop is hit the count is always equal to 0

What do I need to alter so this code executes as I want?

```
static void MoveFiles()
{
    String directoryName = "D:\\_TestData";
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
    if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

    List<String> MyMusicFiles = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\_FinishedData", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp4") || s.EndsWith(".avi") || s.EndsWith(".mkv ")).ToList();

    foreach (string file in MyMusicFiles)
    {
        FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file); 
        if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)     
           mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name); 
    }
}
```

@Renee these are compile errors I get
[image]

Comment: may be it's worth adding ToLower()? Like this: Directory.GetFiles("D:\\_FinishedData", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".mp4") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".avi") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".mkv")).ToList();

Comment: @VladimirChikrizov -> It is still returning 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why that Where construct doesn't work but if all you need is limiting the files to certain extensions handing the selection to the Filesystem feels more effective.

Use this LINQ query to give you an IEnumerable of string with filenames that match your criteria:

```
 var MyMusicFiles  = 
       from search in new [] {"*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.mkv"}
       from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\_FinishedData", search, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       select file;
```

Answer (score 0):

You algorithm can miss folder if you get an exception.  Usually exceptions are caused by not having the privilege to access a file or folder.  Below is code that can be used to allow algorithm to continue after an exception :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteFileNamesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -> I do not want to write the elements about the file, I want to cut them to a different location.  I was using the below -> do you see flaws in this as well or am I safe to stick with this syntax? `foreach (string file in MyMusicFiles)
{
 FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
 if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
  mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
}`

Comment: Yes I see the flaw.  The move is causing the issue.  Whenever you delete an item from a list you have to work from the end to the beginning.  If you have a list 1,2,3,4 and you remove 2 then 3 becomes 2 and 4 becomes three.  You end up skipping 3.  The solution is to use a for loop like this for(i = count -1; i >= 0; i--)